# Mapping int (Id) to Model instance

Tags: automapper

I often have Models and Dtos like this:

```
// DTO class
public class OrderDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    // ...
}

// Model class
public class Order : BaseObject 
{
    public DateTime Date { get set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }

    // ...
}

// Model class
public class Product : BaseObject
{
    // ...
}
```

In order to map my OrderDto to the Order class I have to configure AutoMapper for this particular "association" like so:

```
CreateMap<OrderDto, Order>()
.ForMember(m => m.Product, d => d.ResolveUsing((d, m) =>
{
    return m.Session.GetObjectByKey<Product>(dto.ProductId);
}))
```

This is quite cumbersome to do this for each case like this. Therefore I was looking into generalizing this behaviour by using a custom TypeConverter class:

```
public class IntBaseObjectTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<int, BaseObject>
{
    private UnitOfWork uow;

    // ...

    public BaseObjectConvert(int source, BaseObject destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return uow.Session.GetObjectByKey(typeof(destination), source);
    }
}
```

However, this will fail of course if the destination is null. Unfortunately the ResolutionContext does not give me any clue about the specific type of the destination property.

**Now my question is, if there is another way to achieve with AutoMapper what I would like to do?**

*Please note that I am not using Entity Framework which of course would solve this issue on the model level with foreign key and navigational properties. I use XPO from DevExpress which does not allow foreign key and navigational properties like in Entity Framework.*

Comment: Try a [simple object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/c9370996bde37fd949d53d3c5a6c73bfef69743c/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L96) instead.